# Open Cv Build Error

Tags: opencv

I am trying to install opencv version 3.0.0. I have previously installed version 2.4 with no errors, but this 3.0 version is giving me lots of trouble. I keep running into errors with my make command. Here is the log

```
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videoio
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_videoio
[ 23%] Building CXX object     modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_images.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_mjpeg_decoder.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_v4l.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp.o
usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp: In member function âvoid cv::gphoto2::DigitalCameraCapture::initContext()â:
/usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:325:66: error: invalid conversion from âvoid (*)(GPContext*, const char*, void*) {aka void (*)(_GPContext*, const char*, void*)}â to âGPContextErrorFunc {aka void (*)(_GPContext*, const char*, __va_list_tag*, void*)}â [-fpermissive]
 gp_context_set_error_func(context, ctxErrorFunc, (void*) this);
                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-abilities-list.h:28:0,
             from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-library.h:28,
             from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2.h:49,
             from /usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:32:
/usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-context.h:113:6: error:   initializing argument 2 of âvoid gp_context_set_error_func(GPContext*, GPContextErrorFunc, void*)â [-fpermissive]
 void gp_context_set_error_func     (GPContext *context,
  ^
/usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:326:68: error: invalid conversion from âvoid (*)(GPContext*, const char*, void*) {aka void (*)(_GPContext*, const char*, void*)}â to âGPContextStatusFunc {aka void (*)(_GPContext*, const char*, __va_list_tag*, void*)}â [-fpermissive]
 gp_context_set_status_func(context, ctxStatusFunc, (void*) this);
                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-abilities-list.h:28:0,
             from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-library.h:28,
             from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2.h:49,
             from /usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:32:
/usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-context.h:115:6: error:   initializing argument 2 of âvoid gp_context_set_status_func(GPContext*, GPContextStatusFunc, void*)â [-fpermissive]
void gp_context_set_status_func    (GPContext *context,
  ^
/usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:327:70: error: invalid conversion from âvoid (*)(GPContext*, const char*, void*) {aka void (*)(_GPContext*, const char*, void*)}â to âGPContextMessageFunc {aka void (*)(_GPContext*, const char*, __va_list_tag*, void*)}â [-fpermissive]
 gp_context_set_message_func(context, ctxMessageFunc, (void*) this);
                                                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-abilities-list.h:28:0,
             from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-library.h:28,
             from /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2.h:49,
             from /usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:32:
/usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-context.h:121:6: error:   initializing argument 2 of âvoid gp_context_set_message_func(GPContext*, GPContextMessageFunc, void*)â [-fpermissive]
void gp_context_set_message_func   (GPContext *context,
  ^
/usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:341:52: error: âgp_camera_autodetectâ was not declared in this scope
     CR(gp_camera_autodetect(allDevices, context));
                                                ^
/usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:250:27: note: in definition of macro âCRâ
 if ((r_0629c47b758 = (GPHOTO2_FUN)) < GP_OK) {\
                       ^
/usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp: In member function âint cv::gphoto2::DigitalCameraCapture::widgetDescription(std::ostream&, CameraWidget*) constâ:
/usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:1036:48: error: âgp_widget_get_readonlyâ was not declared in this scope
 CR(gp_widget_get_readonly(widget, &readonly));
                                            ^
/usr/local/src/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp:250:27: note: in definition of macro âCRâ
 if ((r_0629c47b758 = (GPHOTO2_FUN)) < GP_OK) {\
                       ^
make[2]: ***    [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

any idea of what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar issue by installing `libgphoto2-2.5.7` and `gphoto2-2.5.6` from source.

I found [this post](https://hyfrmn.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/install-libgphoto2-and-gphoto2-from-source-on-raspberry-pi/) which helped me and the instructions boil down to (but use `make -j4` to speedup!):

```
sudo apt-get install libltdl-dev libusb-dev libusb-1.0 libexif-dev libpopt-dev

# compile libgphoto2-2.5.7 from source
tar -xvzf libgphoto2-2.5.7.tar.gz
cd libgphoto2-2.5.7
./configure
make -j4 # use all 4 cores of the raspi!
sudo make install

# compile gphoto2-2.5.6 from source
tar -xvzf gphoto2-2.5.6.tar.gz
cd gphoto2-2.5.6
./configure
make -j4 # again use all 4 cores of the raspi!
sudo make install
```

**Beware:** After this gphoto2 library wasn't found so I had to add the line

```
include /usr/local/lib
```

to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then run `ldconfig`...

Answer (score 0):

Two days ago, I have occurred the same issue, and I take the solution Dominic offered. But somehow, it is still something wrong and I [post it in my blog](http://hopingtang.github.io/2016/04/19/opencv-3-1-0-installation-error-note.html).
And today, I have another try. I use `dpkg --get-selections | grep gphoto` to find out what I installed related to gphoto:

`libgphoto2-6:amd64             install`

libgphoto2-6 is still here after I remove gphoto2-2.6 and install gphoto2-2.5.7. So, I remove all gphoto and follow the solution again.
After gphoto installation I use `sudo ldconfig -v` instead. 
And I am now successfully build openCV 3.1.0~

Answer (score -1):

The OpenCV declaration of `ctxMessageFunc/ctxStatusFunc/ctxMessageFunc` has a different parameter list than those defined in gphoto2.

Modify the code to

```
friend void ctxErrorFunc(GPContext *, const char *, va_list args, void *);
friend void ctxStatusFunc(GPContext *, const char *, va_list args, void *);
friend void ctxMessageFunc(GPContext *, const char *, va_list args, void *);
```

and apply the same changes below.

Nonetheless, there are other "function missing" problems, I just commented them out to pass the compilation stage. If you do use the "videoio" module, it's better to get a compatible version of gphoto2.